# Is there a work around to use base64 encoded image string with class ImageComponent.setImageUrl(url)

Tags: image, google-apps-script, base64

Im developing a gmail add on and I would like to show all email attachments in a card grid layout. However the method setImageUrl() in Class ImageComponent doesn't behave like the method setImageUrl() in Class Image which is understandable they're two different classes. The latter you can pass a base64 encoded image string or a url. Is there a way where I can achieve my desired behavior?

Comment: It seems that this can't be done unless you have a url for the ImageComponent [setImageUrl(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/image-component#setimageurlurl). You can create a feature request on Google's Issue Tracker to ask them to allow blobs to be used in that method. You can do it on this link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113